# Is there a way to make a workflow run every Monday?

Tags: workflow, email, date-time, workflow-variable

Context:
I have a list that we use as a sort of newsfeed. I have a workflow which, when an item is created on the newsfeed, copies the contents into a new list item on a secondary list.

What I am trying to do is this:
Every Monday, take all of the contents of the secondary list, compile them into an email, and then clear the list. It essentially sends out a weekly compilation of the news.

Is there a way I can have it check if today is Monday, do actions? Thanks!

Comment: Please check here... they are checking for the Saturday & Sunday in workflow.. You can change it for Monday as per your requirement...http://www.documentmanagementworkflowinfo.com/sample-sharepoint-workflows/sharepoint-designer-workflow-check-today-saturday-sunday.htm

Comment: are you using SharePoint 2013 workflows?

Comment: My suggestion for this is, you should use Timer Job instead of Workflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OOTB way to do this would be to create your workflow as you want it and add a stage at the end. In this stage put in a `Pause` action. You can set this for 7 day (or 168 hours). For your Transition to stage, have it redirect back up to the first stage.

The downside of this would be that you have to manually start it that **first time on Monday**. It would also be one continuous workflow rather than it being ran separately once a week.

Comment: I think you got your answer...right?

Comment: Yes, I will mark it as soon as I can.

Answer (score 5):

I wouldn't do this with workflow, I would do this in a PowerShell script that runs on the server, set it up in a Task Scheduler, and let it run every Monday. The script would kick off the workflow that you want, or alternatively use the PowerShell script to compile and send the email instead of the workflow.

Comment: I like this solution as well, but I am not on a local sharepoint server

Comment: You don't have to be, but its definitely easier. This is Sharepoint Online?

Comment: Yes it is, I am not so familiar